# How do I preseed encrypting just the root partition?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, preseed

I have 3 partitions: EFI (`/boot/efi`), boot (`/boot`) and root (`/`). I want to encrypt *just* `/`. I can do this manually via the installer, but I want to preseed it.

How do I define it? My (non-encrypted) recipe looks something like the below. It is something of a mishmash of suggestions for EFI System Partitions I have found (found no clear guide).

```
boot-root ::
  100 100 100 fat32
    $primary
    $iflabel{ gpt }
    $reusemethod( }
    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ vfat }
    method{ efi } format{ }
    mountpoint{ /boot/efi }
  .
  300 300 300 ext4
    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
    method{ format } format{ }
    mountpoint{ /boot }
  .
  100% 3000 100% ext4
    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
    method{ format } format{ }
    mountpoint{ / }
  .
```

How do I make `sda3` be a physical partition for LUKS-encryption and then have a filesystem on top of that?

UPDATE:

I discovered that I can set the partition to be crypto as below, but there are still 3 issues:

1. I still need to create and activate the encrypted volumes on the chosen partition
2. I still need to set the correct ext4 filesystem on the encrypted volume after created and activated
3. The recipe doesn't select the encryption type to `dm-crypt` which is required for creating and activating the encrypted volumes.

Still struggling mightily

```
boot-root ::
  100 100 100 fat32
    $primary
    $iflabel{ gpt }
    $reusemethod( }
    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ vfat }
    method{ efi } format{ }
    mountpoint{ /boot/efi }
  .
  300 300 300 ext4
    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }
    method{ format } format{ }
    mountpoint{ /boot }
  .
  100% 3000 100% ext4
    method{ crypto } format{ }
  .
```

Comment: FYI, the labels like `sda`, `sdb`, `sdc`, etc don't always keep the same letters (a,b,c) between boots (mine switch every  boot)

Comment: @Xen2050 right you are, `UUID` or `PARTUUID` or `LABEL` or `PARTLABEL` are much better. In my case, I am booting up an image to format, so there is only one drive in. Either way, how do I set it up to crypt single partition? I can do it interactively, but I need it preseeded.

Comment: Hmm, might be getting somewhere, but more questions. Will post other q.

Comment: @deitch - is this a server partition configuration or a client or just a desktop partition example ? These 3 partitions are too few for your intention - there is missing /swap and /home - so you have to set up somehow an extended part of the harddisk with logical partitions - normally partitions allow only 4 on the whole but extended with logical partitions allow 4 times 63 partitions at maximum (and GPT allows much more) ?! - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33555/what-is-the-max-partition-supported-in-linux - regarding master and slaves partitions.

Comment: @dschinn1001 actually its a template for a secure server. The core operating system is on a removable drive. The user data and swap are on an internal drive, which a systemd service finds and mounts appropriately. But ignoring that.... how can I set up the root to be encrypted without LVM?

Answer (score 1):

At first, open a root terminal:

```
sudo -i
```

Then fill the partition, which should be encrypted, with random data using a command like this:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt < /dev/zero > /dev/sdxy
```

You have to replace `sdxy` with the partition which will be encrypted. Then type

```
cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher twofish-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 2000 /dev/sdxy
```

to encrypt the partition `sdxy`. Open the volume and name it `root`:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdxy root
```

Use this command to make an ext4 filesystem inside it:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/root
```

Next you can start the installer. Chose "Something else" when being asked what you would like to do. Then chose the mount points for all your not-encrypted partitions. For your `root` partition, select `/dev/mapper/root`, click "Change". Then select `ext4` for the filesystem type and set the mount point to `/`. Then click "Install now" and install Ubuntu normally.

When finished installing click "Continue testing". Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo -i
cd /mnt
mkdir root
mount /dev/mapper/root root
mount /dev/sdyz root/boot
```

`sdyz` should be replaced with your `boot` partition. Next, type:

```
chroot root
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t sysfs sys /sys
nano /etc/crypttab
```

Open a second terminal and type `sudo blkid`. Find the UUID for `root` (the one that says `crypto_luks` in the end) and paste it into `/etc/crypttab`. Then the file `/etc/crypttab` should look something like this:

```
root UUID=d68911dd-172a-4608-86d4-084eb72f409c none luks
```

Close the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Type `nano /etc/fstab` in the terminal and check if everything looks right (e.g. the UUIDs).

At last, quit the chroot environment and type:

```
cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sdxy --header-backup-file /root/root.img
```

This puts an image of the header of the encrypted partition into the folder `/root` and names it `root.img`. Then move the image to an external drive (in case of forgetting the password). Now you can reboot into your newly installed Ubuntu.

Source: http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Earl you are suggesting building the partition beforehand in a chroot (or containerized) environment, and then sticking it into the installer?

Comment: How would I work that with the preseeder?

Comment: I don't know, but that's at least a solution to make a LUKS-encrypted `root`-partition without LVM.